# Как получить ссылку Uri с userinfo?

Tags: php, uri

Разбираюсь с Uri. Открываю страницу в браузере `http://user:pass@example.com`, но, браузер часть **userinfo** обрезает. В `$_SERVER` этих данных также нет.
Как получить данные или полную ссылку с **userinfo**?

Comment: что такое userinfo ? где браузер обрезает? при чем тут браузер и php?

Comment: @Jean-Claude 1. Часть URI. В моем примере `user:pass` 2. В адресной строке. 3. Ссылки имеют прямое отношение к браузерам и php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

данный формат в RFC3986 от 2005 года помечен как deprecated, а когда работал то данные передавались через заголовок `Authorization`, и, как пишут, в целом пару лет назад еще передавался в актуальных на тот момент версиях браузеров. В пхп заголовки текущего запроса можно получить через `apache_request_headers()`.

Если вы посмотрите в консоли разработчика, то увидите, что в самом запросе, отправляемом браузером, этих сведений нет. Так что и искать их на стороне сервера смысла не имеет.

Comment: Зачем он тогда упоминается в PSR-7\UriInterface?

Comment: @E_K видимо потому что PSR-7 ссылается на этот [RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986), и там user-info все же есть, хоть и помечено как deprecated, . PSR, впрочем, тоже уже не новый  от 2015 года. Также в PSR указывается, что может использоваться при обращении к проекси. тут может это живой формат еще, я таких нюансов не знаю. *"This is often referred to as an absolute URI, and is the only form to specify a URI as detailed in RFC 3986. This form is commonly used when making requests to HTTP proxies." [ссыль](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)*